# Mathematical Induction - Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Prove by induction on $n$ that $K_n$ (the complete graph on n vertices) has a Hamiltonian cycle for all $n \geq 3$.

I understand this can be done not using induction, however I am very new to induction and need as much practice as possible. I have not properly attempted this question yet as I struggle with induction and the best way for me to learn and practice is by reading through examples as that helps me alot. If someone could show me how this is done by induction it would go a long way to helping me understand induction.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This problem should be trivial, I do not see why it would require induction. Let the vertices of $K_n$ be $v_1,v_2\dots v_n$ . Then $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots v_n,v_1$ is a hamiltonian cycle.

Why?

It clearly repeats no vertices except for $v_1$ and every vertex appears. We also have that every pair of consecutive vertices are adjacent because the graph is complete. Finally if an edge was repeated then one of the vertices of the edge would be repeated, however the only vertex that is repeated is $v_1$ and the only two edges that connect $v_1$ are different (Notice that in $K_2$ this is not true when we consider $v_1v_2v_1$).

Comment: Thank you for showing me that it is possible doing it this way, if you also know how to do using induction can you please show me that too? Induction is something I continue to struggle with so the more times I am shown it and more times I can read through and practice it the better

Comment: I think this example is not good practice for induction, because using induction to prove this statement would lead to a very awkward/unnatural proof. There are many good places to find examples of induction problems. If you'd like one in graph theory specifically, I'd suggest trying to prove that every [tournament](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tournament_(graph_theory)) has a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about which would be better induction proofs, however I am still very interested into how this can be done by induction even if it does led to a unnatural proof.